# Map GPS Coordinate to x,y coordinate in rectangle

Tags: python, math, gps, latitude-longitude

I have a rectangle of size 900 * 600. I know top left and bottom right GPS Coordinates in Lat/Long. In  Pixel top left is 0,0 bottom right is 900.600. How can i find x,y coordinate for all GPS coordinates within rectangle?

Comment: I really don't understand this question.  Can you at least post an example, or better yet, the code you have used to try this?  It sounds like you just need to use a ratio.

Comment: Consider a rectangle with top left point as 0,0 inx/y coordinate and bottom right as 900/600 in x/y coordinates. Now GPS Coordinate of Both these point are available. If Some other point lies inside this rectangle with known gps coordinates . How can i find corrosponding x/y coordinates.

Comment: Any further clarification required then please ask

Comment: Convert Lat/Long. Calculate delta. Scale factor according to pixel resolution. Add to reference coord.

Comment: Yes: please post example data, the code you have worked out so far, the result(s) you expect ([mcve]).

Comment: Can u please elaborate ,It will be of help?

Comment: Accuracy depends on scale of "window" due to coordinate projection, so small scale only. I am sure there are libraries that you could use. Good resources come up with https://www.google.com/search?q=coordinate+calculations

Comment: Reverse problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285940/image-pixel-x-y-coordinates-to-lat-lon

Comment: Possibly useful library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/LatLon Q&A on  GIS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91742/looking-for-python-module-to-do-lat-lon-calculations/91745 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838/converting-projected-coordinates-to-lat-lon-using-python

Comment: Sorry but i dont have code. you can ask question please?

Comment: You need to be aware that GPS coordinates live on a sphere (not considering some more elaborated views) and your rectangle is a flat plane. You need to agree on a way to map the sphere to the plane (of which there are quite a few). Once you have that, restricting the mapping to a certain window should not be too hard.